# WSS site and page permission

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have a simple requirement where a user can input some details using a form.I have created a List and using sharepoint designer generated a customized new entry form which can submit data into list.There are two types of users one end user and second admin.

The problem is ,I have to give permission to the list for end users so that they can fill entry and submit request.This permission allow end end user to jump main site and they able to see list data and other site details.

Is there any way which I can create a group which has only access to that entry (request from) page and not able to browse any other urls

I want to use coding level solution if it is possible with in built functionality.
The new customized form is inbuilt functionality.

Please help .

Thanks
Ritu

Answer (score 0):

you can specific permissions on the list, without giving permissions to the whole site. This way you can even give permissions to only add items. All that could be done using the browser alone